# Project Organization

Tags: animation, rigidbody, project

Greetings dear 3D artists! I have a group of objects (3-4 pieces) in one file. These objects are animated using **Rigid Body** physics. I am moving these objects into a common file of a large project. The animation of these objects starts from frame #1. What can I do to make the animation of these objects start at frame #400? Blender version 3.0.

Comment: If you dont want real physics to be simulated from that frame #400 on but only a pre-baked simulation, I would suggest you convert the animation to keyframes and then move them all from #1 to #400. This would even let you parent all rigid bodies to e.g. an empty and place the whole animation somewhere else. For a "new" simulation use the answer by @Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the simulation start value to 400

[image]

and on your objects check "Deactivation"

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome